# How to install Kerberos client on Windows

Tags: ssh, windows-server, kerberos

I had installed KDC server on RHEL and also installed the Kerberos client on Ubuntu. Able to perform the ssh login from client to server through Kerberos.(without password).

Now, I want to use same server that created but Kerberos client should be on windows. 
Can someone help to point out the required steps to be perform on windows to install the Kerberos client on Windows Server.

Thanks,
Hrushi

Answer (score 1):

For use with SSH, there are three system-wide clients available:

- [MIT Kerberos for Windows](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/), providing a GSSAPI Krb5 implementation.
- [Heimdal](http://www.secureendpoints.com/heimdal/), also providing a GSSAPI Krb5 implementation.
- The Windows built-in Kerberos client, accessible via SSPI. It's part of the Active Directory integration – if you join the computer to an AD domain and log in using an AD account, you'll automatically use Kerberos. That said, it's *possible* to use the built-in client even for non-AD realms after some configuration with `ksetup /mapuser` and `runas /netonly`, but not recommended.

Note that some SSH clients might only support SSPI (through native Windows functions), and some might only support GSSAPI (through a library). Current releases of PuTTY support both.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking to go ahead with Heimdal. I do have already installed the KDC on RHEL machine as Kerberos server, will it be matter which client should I select (from above three given) to install on windows.

Comment: Also it would be really helpful if you provide more details steps to go with Heimdal Kerberos configuration and connect to the rhel Kerberos server.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Kerberos on windows by following below links -
http://computing.help.inf.ed.ac.uk/kerberos-windows
http://computing.help.inf.ed.ac.uk/installing-putty

It may be useful for someone